# Redis-HA helm chart with persistancy enabled synch problem

Tags: redis, redis-ha

Currently, we are running persistancy enabled redis-ha with 3 replica (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha v4.4.4) on
kubernetes(RKE - on prem) with longhorn storage class, for some unknown reasons master and slave cant sync. It might happen 30 mins after restart or 1 day after restart eventually we got the errors below.

Slave 1 Error

```
redis-cli role
1) "slave"
2) "10.43.6.52"
3) (integer) 6379
4) "connect"
5) (integer) -1
```

---

```
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:22.843 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue... 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:22.858 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master) 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:28.189 * Full resync from master: bd87e85aa41950b9844c1bcb29a7870b96b53f79:804594411 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.204 # Opening the temp file needed for MASTER <-> REPLICA synchronization: I/O error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.905 * Connecting to MASTER 10.43.6.52:6379 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.905 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.906 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event. 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.906 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue... 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:33.907 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master) 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:36.150 * Full resync from master: bd87e85aa41950b9844c1bcb29a7870b96b53f79:804599892 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:41.163 # Opening the temp file needed for MASTER <-> REPLICA synchronization: I/O error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:41.864 * Connecting to MASTER 10.43.6.52:6379 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:53:41.864 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
```

Slave 2 Error

```
redis-cli role
1) "slave"
2) "10.43.6.52"
3) (integer) 6379
4) "connected"
5) (integer) 809074465
```

---

```
6049:C 22 Sep 2020 09:55:55.091 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /data) for saving: I/O error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:55:55.188 # Background saving error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:56:01.002 * 1 changes in 30 seconds. Saving... 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:56:01.002 * Background saving started by pid 6050 
6050:C 22 Sep 2020 09:56:01.004 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /data) for saving: I/O error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:56:01.102 # Background saving error 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:56:07.013 * 1 changes in 30 seconds. Saving... 
1:S 22 Sep 2020 09:56:07.014 * Background saving started by pid 6051 
6051:C 22 Sep 2020 09:56:07.016 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /data) for saving: I/O error
```

Master Error

```
redis-cli role
1) "master"
2) (integer) 809012256
3) 1) 1) "10.43.254.123"
      2) "6379"
      3) "809011980"
   2) 1) "10.43.229.244"
      2) "6379"
      3) "0"

3944:C 22 Sep 2020 09:57:16.102 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:16.176 * Background saving terminated with success 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:16.176 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:16.177 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 3945 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:21.283 # Connection with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 lost. 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:21.286 # Background transfer error 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:21.601 * Replica 10.43.229.244:6379 asks for synchronization 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:21.601 * Full resync requested by replica 10.43.229.244:6379 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:21.601 * Delay next BGSAVE for diskless SYNC 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:27.241 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:27.243 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 3946 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:32.254 # Connection with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 lost. 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:32.266 # Background transfer error 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:32.563 * Replica 10.43.229.244:6379 asks for synchronization 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:32.563 * Full resync requested by replica 10.43.229.244:6379 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:32.563 * Delay next BGSAVE for diskless SYNC 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:38.304 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:38.304 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 3947 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:43.315 # Connection with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 lost. 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:43.476 # Background transfer error 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:43.517 * Replica 10.43.229.244:6379 asks for synchronization 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:43.517 * Full resync requested by replica 10.43.229.244:6379 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:43.517 * Delay next BGSAVE for diskless SYNC 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.098 * 1 changes in 30 seconds. Saving... 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.098 * Background saving started by pid 3948 
3948:C 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.124 * DB saved on disk 
3948:C 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.124 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.199 * Background saving terminated with success 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.199 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.199 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 3949 
3949:C 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.255 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.299 * Background RDB transfer terminated with success 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.299 # Slave 10.43.229.244:6379 correctly received the streamed RDB file. 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:47.299 * Streamed RDB transfer with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 succeeded (socket). Waiting for REPLCONF ACK from slave to enable streaming 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:52.214 # Connection with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 lost. 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:52.517 * Replica 10.43.229.244:6379 asks for synchronization 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:52.517 * Full resync requested by replica 10.43.229.244:6379 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:52.518 * Delay next BGSAVE for diskless SYNC 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:58.355 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: replicas sockets 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:57:58.357 * Background RDB transfer started by pid 3950 
1:M 22 Sep 2020 09:58:03.422 # Connection with replica 10.43.229.244:6379 lost.
```

Redis conf:

```
dir "/data"
port 6379
maxmemory 0
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
min-replicas-max-lag 5
min-replicas-to-write 1
rdbchecksum yes
rdbcompression yes
repl-diskless-sync yes
save 30 1
timeout 1000
slaveof 10.43.254.123 6379
slave-announce-ip 10.43.6.52
slave-announce-port 6379
```

What I had in mind so far:

- Keys come from RabbitMQ, sometimes developers turn off consumer to stack messeges, stacked messages can make great load on redis, did not find any log
- Longhorn storage class might be broken, did not find any log

I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this, it was due to the Longhorn SC. Migrated to SSD all worked fine.